# Event in User Control does not raise

Tags: c#, events, user-controls, windows, ultrawingrid

I have a User Control that contains a grid and some buttons.
I declare `GridAfterRowActivate` event for User Control:

```
public event EventHandler GridAfterRowActivate;
private void Grid_AfterRowActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GridAfterRowActivate != null)
        GridAfterRowActivate(sender, e);
}
```

I added this User Control to my form. When I fill grid in form constructor, `GridAfterRowActivate` event does not raise. But when I fill grid in `Form_Load`, this event works correctly.

Comment: Hard to imagine a row could be activated when the form is still being constructed.  Find help at Infragistics support channels, http://forums.infragistics.com/

Comment: Easier to help if you say why you can't go the "Form_Load" route?!

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine that it's because you filled the control in the constructor, but the control's Init event isn't called until after the page's `PreInit`.  You should fill the control at the earliest on the page's `Init` event.

Comment: My solution is a windows application not web application.